# How to deploy my first javascript web app onto the web for actual use

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-applications

I built my first javascript app using HTML and CSS as well.  It is a basic tip calculator.  I've pushed my code to my GIT but when i click on website deployed its just the README file.  I have a feeling I need to use Node.js but after the basic reading I did on it I have no idea how to accomplish this. I just want to push the app to heroku or even just off the GIT page to see it in action on another device.

I tried running npm init and it created a package.JSON but every time i pushed to heroku the app would crash and give me an error stating it can not find the "start" script i input.

here's my github for the app, https://github.com/jaronow/tip-calculator. I would appreciate some basic guidance or a link to somewhere i can learn how to accomplish this task

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use Heroku for a one page web app like yours. You can host it directly on Github using [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/). You want to choose the "Project Site" instructions. Pay attention to selecting the "source" when you go through the steps. You'll want to specify your `html/main.html` file.

Also, looking at your code, you should consider renaming your "java" folder either "js" or "javascript" or something similar. Java is a different language and naming it that is confusing.

You do not need to use NodeJS for this project because there is nothing that runs on the server side. Everything runs in the browser: the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

In order to deploy to heroku , you would have to use Node and you will have to set up a basic server to serve your static assets such as the HTML , Images, and CSS.
To deploy or host your app you can use Github pages, I am not sure if you have ever heard of it.
Here is this link: https://pages.github.com/

on the page it should have a step-by-step guide on how to host it.